# Get item's parent scene after QGraphicsScene::addItem ( QGraphicsItem * item )

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I create a new `QGraphicsItem` named `myItem`. And in the *mainwindow.cpp* file I have a `QGraphicsScene scene`. In the constructor of `mainwindow`:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
item = new myItem();
scene->addItem(item);
```

This works fine. I can see my item on the scene. But now I want to get the scene in *myItem.cpp* file. How can I do this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
auto myScene = scene();
```

Please read the [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#scene) first.